# Why do I need to supply a language version when parsing a TypeScript source file?

Tags: typescript

We're using the public api to parse TypeScript files like this:

```
ts.createSourceFile(
    file.name,
    file.textContent,
    languageVersion,
    /*setParentNodes*/ true);
```

We were wondering what the `languageVersion` was for. I don't understand why the parsing of a file should care about what `languageVersion` is used as a target (es3/es5/es2015/esnext).

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different ECMAScript versions have slightly different grammar. `createSourceFile` performs the parsing and needs to know whether to issue certain parser errors on account of this.

You can read https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-identifiers-es6 or other resources to understand how different versions of JS have different parsing rules.

Comment: Brilliant answer once again from you Ryan. Thanks a lot, as well for the linked blog article.